# How can I set the Application Version number in Azure Application Insights for User and Exception data?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I've been working on getting some basic metrics setup within Azure Application Insights. In the Website and the API I am setting the application version using a TelemetryInitializer and am able to filter by this for Server Requests:

```
telemetry.Context.Component.Version = "1.0";
```

When I try to filter or group by Application Version for other types of requests (for example, Users or Exceptions), it shows up as undefined. Does anyone know how to make this kind of filtering work?

Here's what I see in the metrics explorer (ignore all of the undefined requests on the server requests, as they were from before the version was set, and some of the other APIs).

[[image: Current Metrics[1]]

Answer (score 1):

```
telemetry.Context.Component.Version = "1.0";
```

should *totally* work, and it looks like it is for the requests.

couple things i can think of:

1. the exceptions are browser (javascript) exceptions, not server exceptions, so they're not getting your context.
2. the exceptions are occurring either

   a.  *before* you're setting the version on the context, or

   b. are happening on another telemetry context, that doesn't have your version set?

Comment: Good thoughts - I'll give this a try. You're absolutely right that the exceptions are JavaScript exceptions. Let me try just throwing a random exception from the controller and see if it comes through with a version. Any idea where the user stuff gets set? Perhaps that's coming from the view as well and not hitting the Initializer?

Comment: if this is asp.net, user/session info is initially coming from there, and if you are also using the ai javascript sdk, then there's ai cookies getting passed back and forth.